# Can I check what version is Steam gift?

Tags: steam

I've purchased CD-Key for Call of Duty: Ghosts as a Steam gift from a 3rd party site. Can I somehow confirm that it's region free version instead of RU? If it's RU I shouldn't be able to redeem it as a gift, right? Because it's region locked.

Comment: Where did you buy the key from?  Couldn't you just put it in Steam and see what happens?

Comment: My link was deleted so I guess it's forbidden here. Shop name is CDKeysHere. I got it already on my Steam account but I don't want to be suprised in day of release that it's russian version.

Comment: I checked the link, and it says it's [region free](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TT8gW.png).  If you don't trust the site to provide a legitimate game, why would you buy from it?

Comment: I trust them, no problems so far with their games but this time I got some cyrilic letters in my gift message and I'm just curious, that's all.

Comment: @Default I deleted the link because the question can apply to more than just that specific site.  A general answer about steam gifts, regardless of the source of the gift, will give you your answer.

Comment: If the game is gifted via Steam, then the game will not be region locked. You may have to wait for the release in your country to play it, but it won't be locked down. I am pretty confident of this, however I can't find a definitive source. The game can still be removed from your account if Steam can prove something fishy has gone on (seller has obtained keys in an unlawful way for example). In your case, I would deem that scenario very unlikely. Enjoy your game on release :)

Answer (score 1):

Your only place to find information on the content that will be unlocked from a Steam key will come from the vendor that took your money. Otherwise the only option is to try to redeem it, but if your redemption succeeds the content is immediately tied to your account (and not giftable).

Comment: Thanks for answer. Maybe contacting Steam support is a good idea? Or they can "punish" me for buying gift so better no to ask ;)